# Flutter ListView: Only one item name on the list is called when onDismissed

Tags: flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am using a ListView.Builder to display my data to the screen which is working very fine, then I implemented the Dismiss and onDismiss function which seem to be working fine but it I try to dismiss item-A it will dismiss it from the screen but on the showSnackBar its displaying that Item-Z was deleted, if I deleted item-B it still gives me the name of of item-Z on the showSnackBar, I added more items to the data List which made item-Z now item-X but if I swipe its still shows me that the new item-Z has been deleted, then I tried deleting the Last Item which is the item-Z and it gave me an error

> [.  Exception caught by animation library
> ═════════════════════════════════ The following RangeError was thrown
> while notifying listeners for AnimationController:
> **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4**
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:177:60)
> #1      _ListsState.build.. package:another_test/list_widget.dart:81.  ]

this is the code down bellow

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import './list_model.dart';

class Lists extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListsState createState() => _ListsState();
}

class _ListsState extends State<Lists> {
  List<ItemLists> items = [
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Music of the Year',
      discription: 'Davido',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Album Cover design',
      discription: 'Brighter Press',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Vocalist',
      discription: 'Simi-Sola',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Danced',
      discription: 'Black Camaru',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Performance',
      discription: 'Shofeni-Were',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Act',
      discription: 'You Want to See Craze',
      favorite: false,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Dismissible(
            key: ObjectKey(items[index]),
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
              leading: new IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.star,
                    color: items[index].favorite ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  tooltip: 'Add to Favorite',
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      items[index].favorite = !items[index].favorite;
                    });
                  }),
              title: Text('${items[index].title}'),
              subtitle: Text('${items[index].discription}'),
              trailing:
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), onPressed: null),
            )),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              // Remove the item from the data source.
              setState(() {
                items.removeAt(index);
              });
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text('${items[index]?.title} Deleted'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: items.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the data model code down bellow

```
class ItemLists {
  String title;
  String discription;
  bool favorite;

  ItemLists({this.title, this.discription, this.favorite});
}
```

from the screenshoot bellow you will see i deleted a different item but it was still showing me that i deleted the last item which is still on the page

[image]

Comment: Change the key to something somehow unique, like `key: ObjectKey(items[index]).title` and we can see what happens after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snackbar is trying to get the name, but the item is already deleted by that time. The solution would be to get the title name before the item is deleted from the list.

Change onDismissed to this:

```
onDismissed: (direction) {
  // Remove the item from the data source.
  // get the title of the item before it is deleted
  final String myTitle = items[index].title;
  setState(() {
    items.removeAt(index);
  });
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text('$myTitle Deleted'),
    ),
  );
};
```

Comment: Fixed the issue... But I have a question please, how where you able to know where the problem is coming from? Or what should be coursing the issue because from my understanding you just figured out where the issue should be coming from then you checked what was wrong... Please how do I understand flutter to that level? I am able to code when I look at some code examples but actually understanding where an issue should be coming from apart from those displayed by the deburg console is very hard for me to do, I always have to come and post the issyhere... Please help me out

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question and I would be happy to point you in the right direction. If I had an issue similar to yours, the first thing I would do is set a breakpoint to inspect my list and see what is happening to it as I am deleting items from it. If you know nothing about setting breakpoints and inspecting variables I would highly recommend spending 30 mins or an hour learning about it. Google 'breakpoints vscode' (or android studio if u use that).  It will save you a lot of headaches and help you to pinpoint where bugs are happening.

Comment: As for your issue specifically, I knew the issue had something to do with the way you are accessing your list because you are deleting X using its index. However, when you use the same index to get item X's name, instead you get item Y's name. That meant something is happening to the list between deleting and getting the name. Finally, after you delete the last item in the list, you get a RangeError when you try to get its name because the list is empty at that point.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint (for example at the line `final String myTitle = items[index].title;`, the app will pause every time that line runs and you can inspect the contents of the `items` list. If everything seems fine, hit the resume button. When you are happy with your code, remove the breakpoint. This way you can tell if your code is behaving the way you intended it to.

Comment: Thank you very much... I so much appreciate the explanation, one last thing is there any video tutorial you might recommend for an in-depth understanding of Flutter

Comment: Personally, I took Andrea's course which helped me understand a lot of concepts with flutter. https://courses.codewithandrea.com/p/flutter-firebase-time-tracker-app